# Parsing table and removing excess data

Tags: php, simple-html-dom

Im using the [simpel dom parser](http://simplehtmldom.sourceforge.net) to retrieve som data. But when i changed the table layout the parser stopped working. Im getting error `PHP Fatal error:  Call to a member function find() on null`.

```
require('simple_html_dom.php');
$html = file_get_html($url);
$table = $html->find('table');
$rowData = array();

foreach($table->find('tr') as $row) {
    // initialize array to store the cell data from each row
    $stocks = array();
    foreach($row->find('td') as $cell) {
        // push the cell's text to the array
        $stocks[] = $cell->plaintext;
    }
    $rowData[] = $stocks;
}

echo '<table>';
foreach ($rowData as $row => $tr) {
    echo '<tr>'; 
    foreach ($tr as $td)
        echo '<td>' . $td .'</td>';
    echo '</tr>';
}
echo '</table>';
```

Have a look at this [pastebin](http://pastebin.com/rMhVCd9X) (sorry for big table layout). It is from this table i want to extract the following th

```
+--------+--------+------+----+------+-------+--------+--------+---------+
| Aktie  | Senast |  +/- |  % |  Köp |  Sälj |  Högst |  Lägst |  Omsatt |
+--------+--------+------+----+------+-------+--------+--------+---------+
```

This snipp works, but it doesn't arrange the data in a table:

```
require('simple_html_dom.php');
$html = file_get_html($url);

// remove all image
foreach($html->find('img') as $e)
    $e->outertext = '';

// Remove a attribute, set it's value as null! 
foreach($html->find('a') as $e)
$e->href = null;

// Find all <td> in <table> which class=hello 
foreach($html->find('table tr') as $es)
echo $es->innertext . '<br>';
```

**My question:**

- How can i fetch the above mentioned `th`? and insert the corresponding data from `td` column?

Expected result is:

```
+-------------+--------+-------+-------+-------+-------+--------+--------+---------+
|   Aktie     | Senast |  +/-  |   %   |  Köp  |  Sälj |  Högst |  Lägst |  Omsatt |
+-------------+--------+-------+-------+-------+-------+--------+--------+---------+
| AAK AB      | 549,90 | ..etc | ..etc | ..etc | ..etc | ..etc  | ..etc  | ..etc   |
| ABB LTD     | 149.80 | ..etc | ..etc | ..etc | ..etc | ..etc  | ..etc  | ..etc   |
| and so on.. |        |       |       |       |       |        |        |         |
+-------------+--------+-------+-------+-------+-------+--------+--------+---------+
```

Answer (score 0):

Do you have more than one table? If so, [explicitly identify the table id](http://simplehtmldom.sourceforge.net/manual.htm#frag_find_basic)

Get header: `$e = $table->find('thead');` and [do something to it](http://simplehtmldom.sourceforge.net/manual.htm) get the table data, as you already did, and I would imagine that the indexes could implicitly create the relation between header and data.